# Passing variable data between jQuery and PHP using AJAX shorthand

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a search feature that searches a database based on the criteria a user has entered.  Right now, I'm just trying to get the jQuery variable data into PHP.  I've decided to use the shorthand AJAX `$.post` method because this is just a demo project.  I know there are numerous similar questions like mine, but I have yet to find an answer to any of them that I can use.

So what I'm trying to do is, the user will click on a drop down menu and select an option.  AJAX then sends the selected value to the PHP file and the PHP will eventually perform a database search based on what was selected.  The issue is, in PHP, I'm getting a string of `"Search"` when the data is parsed and I echo it but when I do a console log on the variable that was sent, I'm getting the correct text.  Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Here's what I have so far. 
**AJAX**

```
$("#search_form").on("submit", function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.post("../php/test.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
})
```

**PHP**

```
ob_start();
require("../includes/header.php");
$criteria = $_POST["search"];
ob_clean();
echo $criteria;
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="search_form" method="post">
    <fieldset id="search_by">
        <div class="select" name="searchBy" id="searchBy">
            <p>Search By...</p>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <div class="option-menu">
            <div class="option">Airport Identifier</div>
            <div class="option">Top Rated</div>
            <div class="option">Instructor</div>
            <div class="option">Malfunctions/Maneuvers</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Search_Now" />
</fieldset>
```

**As Requested**

Here is a fiddle of the drop down menu to show how it works.
http://jsfiddle.net/xvmxc0zo/

Comment: So if you do `console.log(search);` right after `var search = $(this).text();`, you get the expected text and not "Search"?

Comment: @PatrickQ exactly.  But when I do a PHP echo, I get "Search"

Comment: Are you using some jQuery plugin related to your dropdown? If so, it would be helpful to see the rendered HTML, not just the original HTML.

Comment: @PatrickQ, no, it's a custom HTML/CSS/jQuery dropdown I created myself, there is no rendered HTML, mainly because I don't know how to create plugins.

Comment: Sounds like the `submit` element is being submitted instead. Do submit elements manifest in the submitted data or do you have another element with `name="search"` and `value="Search"`? Just to verify, can you change the `submit` value to `Search Now` and confirm if the data value changed too. If so, the form is being submitted instead of the ajax.

Comment: Could you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing the dropdown in action (without the ajax part)?

Comment: This is the only place I have the search name/id in the HTML.  However, I was setting an action to the HTML form to call the PHP script.  Once I removed that though the echo no longer 'worked' and the page simply refreshed.

Comment: @PeterKA you're right that the submit element is what's being submitted.  Why would it be doing that though?  How do I fix it?

Comment: Great, @Robert! That should help a great deal. Take a look at my answer below.

Comment: @PeterKA I just saw your answer, we must've been typing at the same time, I'm testing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is being submitted via default form submission; the ajax call is misplaced, it should be within the `submit` handler, which should prevent default form submission.

**Note** that I have removed both `name` and `id` attributes from the `submit` button; you do not need them. Just let the submit button do it's job and listen for the submit event on the form where you would then use `event.preventDefault();` to make sure the form does not submit, then you can make your ajax call.

```js
$("#searchBy").on("click", ".option", function(){
    $('#search').val( $(this).text() );
});

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("../php/test.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data){
        //jsonData = window.JSON.parse(data);
        console.log( data);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<fieldset id="search_by">
    <div class="select" name="searchBy" id="searchBy">
        <p>Search By...</p>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="option-menu">
            <div class="option">Airport Identifier</div>
            <div class="option">Top Rated</div>
            <div class="option">Instructor</div>
            <div class="option">Malfunctions/Maneuvers</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="search" id="search" />
    <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" />
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Search" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

In your PHP use `echo $criteria;` instead of `echo json_encode($criteria);`.

Comment: I'm getting a `null` value in the console log.

Comment: Getting closer now. Please make the suggested changes in the `$.post()` callback and your PHP script.

Comment: I tried the updated answer, but instead of giving me null, I'm now getting an empty string.  I'm editing my question to reflect what I did.

Comment: That's because the textbox I renamed `search` may be empty. Did you include this line in the click hander `$('#search').val( $(this).text() );` and did do you see the clicked text in the textbox before clicking submit?

Comment: Actually, the text box isn't the issue it's actually irrelevant right now, it's the drop down menu that I'm having issues with.  I should probably remove the text box from the code.

Comment: Please change `<input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" />` to `<input type="text" name="search" id="search" />`

Comment: I understand that. Just for proof of concept you may have to make all the changes I have made, exactly as they are :( Once you're are satisfied you with the way the code works, feel free to tweak it however you want.

Comment: I'm getting the same results

Comment: Same results meaning?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, never mind I just saw what you did in the first click event.  So would this work if I needed to have the user select an option and type in something different in the text box?  Say I want them to search by instructor and then have them type in a name.....

Comment: Yes, it would. Whatever other form elements you have would be submitted too `$('form').serialize()` gets all the form data for you. Now that you see how it works you can actually have a hidden form element to hold the user's selection ... then you can have a visible textbox where they can enter text.

Comment: Awesomeness.  Thank you very much for sticking with this and helping me out.

Comment: No problem. Once you verify all that, feel free to accept the answer for the sake of others that may have a similar issue. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use [the way of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/change/) documentation to check changes in your drop down.

```
$( "select" ).change(function () {
  $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
    $.post("../php/test.php", {search: $(this).text()}, function(data){
      jsonData = window.JSON.parse(data);
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: I'm actually getting the same exact thing doing it this way

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "Search" on the PHP side because that is the value of your submit button.

You want the post to occur when you click on an option?  Try adjusting your selector as follows:

```
$("#searchBy .option").on("click", function () {
    var search = $(this).text().trim();
    $.post("../php/test.php", { search: search }, function (data) {
        jsonData = window.JSON.parse(data);
    })
});
```

Comment: I am still getting the same results using this method.  I'm wanting the post on the PHP side to occur when the user hits the submit button.  Why would it return the value of the button though?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `header.php` is provoking the error. I created a test file myself with your code and that works perfectly fine:

```
<?php
    if($_POST)
    {
        ob_start();
        //require("../includes/header.php");
        $criteria = $_POST["search"];
        ob_clean();
        echo json_encode($criteria);
        exit;
    }
?>
<fieldset id="search_by">
    <div class="select" name="searchBy" id="searchBy">
        <p>Search By...</p>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="option-menu">
            <div class="option">Airport Identifier</div>
            <div class="option">Top Rated</div>
            <div class="option">Instructor</div>
            <div class="option">Malfunctions/Maneuvers</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" />
    <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" class="button" value="Search" />
</fieldset>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $("#searchBy").on("click", ".option", function(){
        var search = $(this).text();
        $.post("<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>", {search: search}, function(data){
            jsonData = window.JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(jsonData); //Prints the correct string
        })
    });

</script>
```

Comment: The header only holds the site's template, external scripts, external stylesheet, and database connection info if it's needed.  That shouldn't be causing an issue.  As I said, the console is already printing the correct string, it's the PHP echo that isn't